# How to use conda from Jupyter Lab terminal?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab

Question in the title. What I've tried: Installing `nb_conda` and `nb_conda_kernels`. This did allow me to choose the environment my kernel runs in. However, I am unable to use `conda` from the terminal inside the Jupyter Lab notebook.

**Before launching Jupyter Lab:**

```
(base)
wesle@DESKTOP-VV4V3ND MINGW64 ~/Jupyter Notebooks/jn-anomaly-detect (master)
$ conda activate general-ml

(general-ml)
wesle@DESKTOP-VV4V3ND MINGW64 ~/Jupyter Notebooks/jn-anomaly-detect (master)
$ jupyter lab
```

**From Jupyter Lab terminal:**

Change the kernel to run in the `general-ml` conda environment, then open up a notebook terminal:

```
wesle@DESKTOP-VV4V3ND MINGW64 ~/Jupyter Notebooks/jn-anomaly-detect (master)
$ conda info -e
bash: conda: command not found
```

as if it doesn't exist at all. Is there a known solution to this?

**Edit:**

I noticed that packages installed from Anaconda Navigator GUI are reflected live in Jupyter Notebook. This is an undesirable workaround as it is not efficient to open a new program, navigate through the gui, search for a package then install. All of this could be done from the terminal in 3 seconds.

Comment: [The `nb_conda` package](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda#nb_conda) is supposed to provide the same functionality of Anaconda Navigator in Jupyter. This should appear as a tab in the Jupyter interface, from which you can create, mutate (install/update/remove packages), or remove environments. I'd verify again that `nb_conda` is installed, and if still an issue, perhaps post an image of what you see in Jupyter. Might also be worth searching through or posting an [Issue on the repo](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues).

Comment: @merv Thanks, yeah I just verified that `nb_conda` is indeed installed. I suspected it was because I can choose to run kernels in specific conda environments now which was a new feature after I attempted to install it. However, I see no way to open this native Anaconda GUI inside of Jupyter Lab. And besides, even if I could find this GUI tab I'm specifically asking about how to use the Anaconda command line tool `conda` from a Jupyter Lab terminal. Let me know if you think of anything!